# Handling view clicks inside Fragment instead of Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using `ViewPager`, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `Fragment`. 
How can I load each fragment with it's functionality (first initialization, button handlers)?

I manage to make the buttons to work but I had to move all the handles in the main activity. How can I keep the functionality in the fragment?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0: return "A";
            case 1: return "B";
            case 2: return "C";
        }

        return "Tab " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment:

```
public class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    int mNum;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page, container, false);

        //((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
        //        Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Here is the *activity_page.xml*

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#fffaffff"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".GuessActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_validate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guess_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="validateGuess"
            android:text="@string/button_validate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="@string/guess_success"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#008000"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: There aren't any references to buttons in your code, nor to any button handlers in the activity.

Comment: The buttons and handlers are in activity_page.xaml. I'll add that too. 1 sec

Comment: if your handlers are linked using the `onClick` attribute, you cannot have the corresponding method in the fragment. You will need to get a reference to the button from within your fragment, and assign it an onClickListener using something like `myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {...})`

Comment: ok, but how can I keep this nice and clean if I have multiple fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't seem to be about swiping really, but rather how to keep code relating to a particular screen grouped together.

Currently you use the `onClick` attribute in your activity layout, on elements where you want to handle the click. The contract for this attribute requires a public void method in your activity, taking a single `View` object as parameter, with the same name as the value of the attribute. E.g. if you had:

```
<View ...
  android:onClick="onButtonPress" />
```

you'd need the corresponding method in your activity:

```
public void onButtonPress(View view) {
    ...
}
```

Assuming that each of your fragments have a different UI (a different XML layout) and you want to keep the logic for each one inside the fragment, I would start with a stricter naming convention.

Currently your DemoObjectFragment's layout is called `activity_page.xml`. Consider reserving `activity_` prefix for layouts that you will use in your activities. Instead try `fragment_demo_object.xml` for this particular fragment.

You instantiate this fragment's layout in `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` which is correct. Before you return the root view, you can find your views, as you have done, though they are commented out.

```
private Button validateButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page, container, false);
    validateButton = (Button) rootView.findById(R.id.button_validate);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    validateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validateInput();
        }
    });
}

private void validateInput() {
    // validate whatever you want to validate
}
```

In this case, the logic for the UI on a particular fragment is only on that fragment.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution that I was looking for.